# Why does ObjectId make sharding easier in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I keep reading that using an ObjectId as the unique key makes sharding easier, but I haven't seen a relatively detailed explanation as to why that is. Could someone shed some light on this?

The reason I ask is that I want to use an english string (which will be unique obviously) as the unique key, but want to make sure that it won't tie my hands later on.

Comment: No, it will not tie your hands. If you want "official" confirmation for this, you can ask on official Mongo Users list on Google groups and see if you get a reply from someone from Mongo team.

Answer (score 4):

I've just recently been getting familiar with mongoDB myself so take this with a grain of salt but I suspect that sharding is probably more efficient when using ObjectId rather that your own key values because of the fact that part of the ObjectId will point out which machine or shard that the document was created on. The bottom of this page in the [mongo docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-DocumentIDs%3A%5Cid) explains what each portion of the ObjectId means.

Answer (score 3):

I asked this question on Mongo user list and basically the reply was that it's OK to generate your own value of _id and it will not make sharding more difficult. For me sometimes it's necessary to have numeric values on _id like when I'm going to use them in url, so I'm generating my own _id in some collections.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't add this as another field and access it that way?

Comment: Rails puts the id in the url for a resource by default. I just wanted something a little more readable.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId is designed to be globally unique. So, when used as a primary key and a new record is appended to the dataset without primary key value, then each shard can generate a new objectid and not worry about collisions with other shards. This somewhat simplifies life for everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Shard key does not have to be unique. We can't conclude that sharding a collection based on object id is always efficient .

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ObjectID is probably a poor choice for a shard key.

From the docs (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-internals/ the section on "Write Scaling"):

"[T]he most significant bits of [an ObjectID] represent a time stamp, which means that they increment in a regular and predictable pattern. [Therefore] all insert operations will be storing data into a single chunk, and therefore, a single shard. As a result, the write capacity of this shard will define the effective write capacity of the cluster."

In other words, because every OID sorts "bigger" than the one created immediately before it, an inserts that are keyed by OID will land on the same machine, and the write I/O capacity of that one machine will be the total I/O of your entire cluster.  (This is true not just of OIDs, but any predictable key -- timestamps, autoincrementing numbers, etc.)

Contrariwise, if you chose a random string as your shard key, writes would tend to distribute evenly over the cluster, and your throughput would be the total I/O of the whole cluster.

(EDIT to be complete: with an OID shard key, as new records landed on the "rightmost" shard, the balancer would handle moving them elsewhere, so they would eventually end up on other machines.  But that doesn't solve the I/O problem; it actually makes it worse.)